# Matlab : How to extract elements in a uniform interval?

Tags: matlab, extract, intervals, uniform

I have a `(5160 X 4)` matrix.

I want to extract just `(1,1),(41,1),(81,1),(121,1)........` in a uniform interval, only from the first column of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `data` is your matrix, you can do this:

```
A = data(1:40:5160,1);
```

The `1:40:5160` will create an array such that it starts at 1, and goes up in increments of 40 as much as possible up until 5160.  Once you create `1:40:5160`, you can use this array and access the corresponding rows, and you are accessing the first column using the index of 1 for the second parameter.  Actually, the last row that gets extracted is 5121.  We aren't able to go up to 5161 due to the fact that your matrix has 5160 rows, and we have also specified 5160 as the ending of the indexing.

**NB:** This is very basic MATLAB syntax. Any standard MATLAB tutorial should teach you this.

Comment: @user3667329: You're very welcome.  If this has helped you, please consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark icon belong the up and down arrows to the left of my answer.

Comment: I checked it!! May I have to ask more question in 'add comment' or making new one?

Comment: @user3667329: Go ahead and make a new one.  Let me know when it's up.